# How to restore my iPod

Tags: ios, jailbreak

How can i restore my jailbroken iPod 4th gen iOS 6.1.6.
When i restore from iTunes it shows an error" iPod could not be restore an unknown error(3096) occurred".

What can i do for restoring my iPod .

Answer (score 1):

You need to put it into DFU mode. See [this OS X Daily article](http://osxdaily.com/2010/06/24/iphone-dfu-mode-explained-and-how-to-enter-dfu-mode-on-your-iphone/) for instructions. Basically

- Connect the iPhone to your computer and launch iTunes
- Turn the iPhone off (hold down the power button at the top of the iPhone)
- Hold down the sleep/power button and home button together for exactly 10 seconds, then release the power button
- Continue to hold down the Home button until a message appears in iTunes telling you an iPhone in recover mode has been detected

When you are in DFU mode your iPhone screen will be completely black. Even though the screen is black, that doesn’t mean the device can’t be interfaced with either iTunes or a custom firmware client (for jailbreaking, etc).